# How to uninstall preinstalled apps and games in my Galaxy Note GT tablet?

Tags: samsung

My Samsung galaxy note GT - n5110 has something wrong and im not sure what. Few months now I can't use it because it keeps restarted and games and apps are just downloading without my permission. I have factory reset it and any other reset there is and now the games that had installed are pre installed so when I factory reset my tab all the games are there and you can't delete them? Does anyone know how to fix it?!!

Comment: Sounds like you've caught a persistend malware which managed to integrate itself into the system, so a factory-reset doesn't clean it up. In that case, the only way out is [flashing a clean ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info).

Answer (score 0):

1) Google Play: find 'malwarebytes' app (log looks like a bat).

2) See if it changes anything. (Probably not malware after all).

3) Back to Google Play: search 'app remover'.

4) Spend some time finding the right one for you: Some need Root, some don't.

5) Use the app to remove unwanted system apps but BE CAREFUL not to remove critical ones!!